# Sliding a div in with jQuery on scroll event

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to fade in a "slide" at the bottom of my page, it's a little tab that's supposed to stick to the right side. I'm currently fading it on a delay, but I'd like to fade it in when the user scrolls down.

This, though, keeps sliding the div across the page, instead of leaving it stuck to the side.

```
   $(function() {
        var slide = $("div[data-slide='true']");

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
            console.log(pos);
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
                 slide.animate({opacity: 1,right:'+=350'},1350, 'swing').stop();

           } else {
                 slide.clearQueue().animate({opacity: 0,right:'-=350'},500, 'easeOutBounce');
           }
        });

    });
```

How do I stop the sliding once the initial waypoint is reached? I seem to be able to unbind the scroll event with `$(window).unbind('scroll');` but then the slide never animates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting a new animation to +350px each time the scroll event is fired, that's why it's moving across the page.
I made a little test to prevent that. I basically add two vars (opening and closing) to prevent the animation from starting multiple times, and changed the animation itself a bit:

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/B7pJL/1/

JS:

```
var slide = $("div[data-slide='true']");
var opening = false;
var closing = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(pos);
    if (pos > 100) {
        if (!opening) {
            opening = true; closing = false;
            slide.stop().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                'margin-left': -350
            }, 1350, function() {
                opening = false;
            });
        }

    } else {
        if (!closing) {
            closing = true; opening = false;
            slide.stop().animate({
                opacity: 0,
                'margin-left': 0
            }, 500, function() {
                closing = false;
            });
        }
    }
});​
```